# Global Costmap only publishing once to a subscriber?

Tags: navigation, move-base, costmap-2d, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello.

I'm using the amcl_demo.launch file to localize to a static map, and gather costmap data of the environment. When I try to subscribe to the global_costmap/costmap topic, it only publishes once, and will not update the value. The same effect is seen when using rostopic echo. Rviz can update the global costmap display, so I don't know what the issue is. Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/109901/global-costmap-only-publishing-once-to-a-subscriber?/) by [Bobby9002](https://answers.ros.org/users/9831/bobby9002/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-12-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You also need to subscribe to costmap_updates.

**Edit**: I have uploaded an example of how to combine the topics here: https://github.com/DLu/navigation/commit/92b5a4f2a2c6788bd1d7616c21694b1e49c548c0

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2014-05-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alex920a](https://answers.ros.org/users/14481/alex920a/) on 2014-08-29**:
I would like to have more info. I'm trying to subscribe to costmap_updates but I obtain: Is /clock being published?

Also in Rviz the global costmap won't update